# Правильно ли написано предложение с составным союзом?

Tags: синтаксис

Правильно ли написано предложение с составным союзом:
«Гражданину важно не только, чтобы его нарушенное право восстанавливалось, а нарушители  карались по справедливости, но и чтобы его права не нарушались вовсе»?

Comment: По-моему, в конструкции "не только чтобы" запятая не нужна. Нечто подобное я встречал где-то у Розенталя.

Answer (score 1):

Это сложное предложение с разными видами связей. Чтобы было нагляднее, я уберу одну часть. *Гражданину важно не только чтобы его нарушенное право восстанавливалось,  но и чтобы его права не нарушались вовсе*. **Главная часть**: *Гражданину важно*. Что? **Придаточные**:*чтобы его нарушенное право восстанавливалось*. И важно еще что? *чтобы его права не нарушались вовсе*. Это однородные придаточные. Запятые ставятся по правилу постановки запятых при однородных членах в простом предложении, т.е. между однородными членами. Однородные придаточные соединены союзом *не только ..., но и* , запятая ставится перед второй частью двойного союза.  Если бы однородные придаточные были бы соединены одиночным союзом и (или), запятая бы не ставилась.  *Гражданину важно, чтобы его нарушенное право восстанавливалось и чтобы его права не нарушались вовсе* .

Данное в вопросе предложение немного сложнее, так как первая придаточная часть представляет собой 2 части, соединенные союзом а, перед ним, соответственно, запятая.

Comment: Ларf, я что-то не понял момента, почему с "только" запятой перед чтобы нет, а без него есть. Ведь эта запятая не разделяет два однородных придаточных, а отделяет их от главной части. 

А если так: *"Гражданин заинтересован не только в том чтобы его нарушенное право восстанавливалось и нарушители карались по справедливости и ожидает не только чтобы соблюдались его права...."*? Вообще без запятой получается? С таким количеством придаточнх?  

Кстати, судя опять-таки по Нацкорпусу в текстах столетней давности запятая между "не только" и "чтобы" регулярно ставится. Позднее - уже нет.

Comment: В этом примере нет однородных придаточных. НО есть грамматическая ошибка. Начало союза есть, а продолжения нет (не только ...,но и ). Предложение Вы специально составили, иначе бы выразились понятнее, слишком уж далеко друг от друга однородные сказуемые.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько понимаю, основной вопрос в запятой между "не только" и "чтобы".
Она не нужна. Вот самое простое и логичное (на мой вкус) тому объяснение.

Вопрос № 251644

"Члены клуба приходят сюда не только (,) чтобы изысканно поесть, но и пообщаться, обсудить дела". Нужна ли запятая? Почему?

olgame

*Ответ справочной службы русского языка*

Запятая не нужна. Не ставится запятая между главной и придаточной частью, если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит отрицательная частица не.

ЗЫ Если что, это цитата из Розеталя, [Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm), §107 примечание 2.

Comment: А в это примере все правильно. Есть составной союз не только ...но и. который соединяет однородные придаточные. Запятая стоит между однородными придаточными.